# Text overlay image (css)

Tags: html, css

This is really frustrating! How do I make the < h2> go on the bottom of the image, not the bottom of the text?

https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/gRxMqG/

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="header-link">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/haP17k/umbrella.jpg" width="300" height="auto" alt="umbrella" border="0">
    <h2>Artificial Intelligence & Blockchain Interest</h2>
  </div>
    <p>Learning more every day about Ethereum and other blockchain technologies!</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: remove the position absolute on the h2, why are you absolute positioning that?

Comment: So the text goes on the bottom of the image https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Comment: Set bottom to a positive number, ie 100px instead of 0

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwLZpy

Comment: Fixed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this maybe?

- Replace the `<img>` with a `<div>` and use the image as a background for that div
- Include the h2 within that div
- Apply `position: relative` to the div
- Apply `position: absolute` to the h2, since an absolute positioned element is positioned

> at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor

([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position))

```css
.header-img {
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/haP17k/umbrella.jpg') center center no-repeat / 100% 100%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="header-link">
    <div class="header-img">
      <h2>Artificial Intelligence & Blockchain Interest</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
    <p>Learning more every day about Ethereum and other blockchain technologies!</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
  </div>
```